# The split cell short-cut does not work in IPython-notebook

Tags: split, cell, jupyter-notebook, shortcut

I am using IPython-notebook 4.0.4 and IPython 4.0.0 on Mac. 
The short-cut for cell split Control+Shift or Control+Shift+subtract does not work for me. 
Could someone help me please?